# I want to measure websites with restricted access with Page Speed ​Insight

Tags: seo, ip-address, page-speed, google-pagespeed

I want to measure websites with IP access restrictions in the development environment etc. with [Google's Page Speed ​​Insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started).

Is it possible to use the above web services and APIs?
If the access source is a fixed IP address, it may be possible by allowing that IP to the white list.

Comment: Can you make do with [lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse) which is a chrome plugin that you can run yourself rather than trying to get page speed insights to access your staging server?

Comment: thank you.The result of lighthouse varies depending on the specifications of the local machine and the communication environment.so I want to get third-party results with pagespeed insights provided by Google.